# Find the probability that a person chosen at random from this group has a hot breakfast and a hot lunch

Tags: probability

In a large group of people it is known that 10% have a hot breakfast, 20% have a hot lunch and 25% have a hot breakfast or a hot lunch. Find the probability that a person chosen at random from this group has a hot breakfast and a hot lunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5%, you are welcome.

Now really, get a book, or just draw it on a piece of paper.
You have a blob with an area of 20, and another one with the area of 10. And you also know that they combined area is 25.

This would be the sketch then (just they are not really blobs, but lines):

```
1111111111                        <= 10"%" representing the breakfast people
          22222222222222222222    <= 20"%" representing the lunch people
3333333333333333333333333         <= 25"%" representing the breakfast and/or lunch people
     22222222222222222222         <= 20"%" representing the lunch people is pulled towards
                                     the left, so its combined area (length) with 1-s
                                     matches with the 3-s
     44444                        =>  5"%" happens to be their intersection
```

(For the downvoters: it is not the way how you *calculate* it in everyday life, but this is the way how you *understand* it as a beginner - my bet would be that OP has seen the P(x) notation in a class already, but it does not work well without the understanding part)

Comment: Those 2 immediate downvotes, lol

Comment: please given on sketch.

Comment: @RedAnz decorated 'sketch' is present.

Comment: +1 for using a drawing to illustrate some basic probability, and (I wish I could +1 again!) for setting a random sample size of 100, which really helps simplify the problem using numbers!

Comment: @TobyMak thank you (however the nice numbers come from the question itself)

Comment: @tevemadar I ask my friends answer. They asked to me 0.025% but my answer and your answer same. i not to trust my friends answer.

Comment: @RedAnz your friend might have divided their answer by 2 on the basis of having 2 sets of people (which could have some role in a different task, but not here). The 5% (0.05) itself is good for sure, see proper calculation in fonfonx's post too.

Comment: I have removed an initial downvote due to having viewed an incomplete answer, for which I apologize. Next time, I shall wait for a complete answer before voting.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be some person. Let $L$ the event "x has a hot lunch", $B$ the event "x has a hot breakfast".

Then $$\mathbb P (B \cap L) = \mathbb P(B) + \mathbb P(L) - \mathbb P(B \cup L) = 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.25 = 0.05$$

Then the probability to have a hot breakfast and a hot lunch is 5%.